# Ajax redirect using POST

Tags: ajax, post, redirect

He have seen a lot of answers on how to redirect to a different page after a successful Ajax call, but all of them uses a GET method.
I'd like, instead, to pass my parameters to the new page using the POST method.
How can i do it?

Comment: The parameters aren't stored in the POST request like they are in the GET request, so you'd have to pass your parameters in a different manner.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, do you wish to redirect the current page to a new URL without AJAX, as if submitting a form normally with the browser, or do you wish for the original AJAX POST to be now directed to a new URL using another AJAX POST (instead of a GET) in the case of a 301 Permanent Redirect Response?

Answer (score 2):

Well i have faced this issue before and the only way to do this seems(maybe i am wrong) to be by defining a AJAX success callback function and redirect from that callback function. If you want you can send back the redirect url itself in the AJAX response and read the redirect URL in the call back function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't programmatically set the browser to do a POST request, only an `XMLHTTPRequest` one.  The best you can do is simulate it by creating a new `form` element with the data you want to submit, then calling `submit` on it:

```
var params = {name: 'lonesomeday', website: 'stackoverflow'};

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'http://example.com';
form.method = 'post';

for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        var field = document.createElement('input');
        field.type = 'hidden';
        field.name = key;
        field.value = params[key]

        form.appendChild(field);
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Comment: You can send a request with the POST request method using XMLHttpRequest... I think creating a new form to do the submit is overkill?

Comment: @jamiebarrow I would argue the opposite.  Doing a whole XMLHTTPRequest solely in order to get a URL to go to when you could do the whole operation in one HTTP request is overkill.

Comment: hmm, yesterday I read this differently. I had a problem that when doing an AJAX POST (using jQuery.ajax) to a URL where the response is a 301 permanent redirect, the library performs a GET request to the new Location. It should however in my scenario do a POST to the new URL via AJAX, not redirect the current page normally to a new URL. After reading this again, it appears that the O.P. is asking how to redirect the page after doing a normal AJAX POST, got myself confused :) Sorry if I confused others too! :)