# Redirect to a page with POST data and custom headers

Tags: javascript, php

I want to redirect a page and attach **POST** params and **Custom headers** to it e.g.

```
$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['CAPA_Type'] = "createPlan";
$data_to_post['CAPA_Gateway'] = "PayStack";

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "CAPA_token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Submitting a form dynamically from JS doesn't work, because it cannot send custom headers, AJAX is not an option as I want to open the url in browser not in the background. Is it possible to achieve this in JS or PHP? If it is, how would one go about doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax redirect using POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596737/ajax-redirect-using-post)

Comment: @FrayneKonok But that would be GET request not POST.

Comment: are you implementing a payment gateway ??? submit your form to a `php` page where you can set your `headers` and `post` params and redirect to next page, everything will go on synchronously.

Comment: @HirdeshVishwdewa I want to redirect to a URL with POST data and Custom Headers attached to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514692/set-custom-header-then-redirect

Comment: have you tried curl?

Comment: @ParagBhayani Yes I tried Curl it didn't work.

Comment: @mega6382: wasn't this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558946/redirect-a-url-with-post-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this as you want, further possible solutions are using [php cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or Carl McDade's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653090/how-do-you-post-to-a-page-using-the-php-header-function) or what I describe below.

You can do this as well->

1. Submit your form to a php page where you can make a hidden-form with your POST params,
2. onload of this PHP page submit the hidden-form (to the URL where you want to redirect) using JS `form.submit()`.

Just like we see this in case of payment gateways, also everything will happen in synchronous(not in background) manner.

Ultimately you will be on your final page with `POST` params and `custom headers`.

Thanks

Comment: How do I pass the custom headers?

Comment: as far i know its not possible what you want to do... there can be some possible workarounds out there. Also, I have updated my answer pls see.